# How to do auto save with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

How to do autosave with `rxjs` follows by these criteria?

- Click on save button should make http request to save my data (from local variable, not form).
- Every 3000ms (interval) should do the same like I clicked the button.
- Can't be parallel http request. Until request is active another request should not run until its finished. if the request is begin, then all other requests should wait in the queue (and then execute one-by-one).
- The save button should gets high priority in the queue/execute.

I want to use the power of rxjs, so it will be nice to do it by rxjs operators rather than local variables (`if (this.requestStart === true)`).

This is want I accomplish this far. Any help will appreciated

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, interval} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `

  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <button (click)="save()">save</button>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() {
    interval(3000)
      .subscribe(val => this.makeRequest());

  }

  save() {
    this.makeRequest().subscribe(res => {
      console.log({ res });
    });
  }

  makeRequest() {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next({ save: true });
        observer.complete();
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` along with `exhaustMap` to make sure only one request at a time is handled.

Something like:

```
// Get a btn reference
const btnEl = document.getElementById('send-btn');

merge(
  fromEvent(btnEl, 'click'),
  interval(3000)
).pipe(
  concatMap(_ => this.makeRequest())
)
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log({ res });
});
```

It's not going to be easy to achieve prioritization, `rxjs` is not built around queuing in this sense.

Comment: you will lose source event if it happens before makerequest finish

Comment: Correct, probably not what Jon wanted. I updated the answer using `concatMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap` and `concatMap` for this occasion:

```
manualSave$ = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.manualSave$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 3 * 1000)),
    concatMap(() => this.makeRequest())
  ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  this.manualSave$.next(); // to start it off
}

save() {
  this.manualSave$.next();
}

makeRequest() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

What happens is this:

```
---1---2---3---4---5---6---...
-----X------X------------X-...
      switchMap                // Preserves 3 second interval after every save
                               // Unless interrupted by a manual save
---A-B---A--B---A---A---AB-... // A: http request generated from autosave
                               // B: http request generated from manual save
      concatMap
---ResResResRes-Res-Res-ResRes-... 
                   // Concats one request only after the last one is finished
```

I prefer using `switchMap` over a merge, because `merge` does this:

```
---1----2----3----4----5----6---...
-----X--------X-------------X---...
      merge
---1-X--2----3X---4----5----(6X)...
```

While `switchMap` cancels previous values and does this:

```
---1----2----3----4----5----6---...
-----X--------X-------------X---...
      switchMap
---1-X----2---X----4----5---X---...
```

only making the necessary amount of requests.